# Taylor series question help!

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

This question is on a past paper for my exam but no model solutions have been provided and I'm worried I'm doing completely the wrong thing,

Consider two functions represented by Taylor (MacLaurin) series:

$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$  ,

$g(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_{n}x^{n}$

for $x$ in some interval $(−r, r)$. Write down the formula for an in terms of the
derivatives of $f$. By applying this formula to the product $fg$, find the first
three Taylor coefficients $c_{0},c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ (about the origin) of $fg$. What are the
Taylor polynomials of order 2 at the origin of $f, g$ and $fg$ where:

$f(x) = e^{x}$

$g(x) = \sin(x)$

My current answer is that the formula general formula for $a_{n}$ is $\frac{f^{(n)}(n)}{n!}$
and that the Taylor polynomials with the given functions are:

$f(x) : 1 + x + \frac{x^{2}}2$

$g(x) : x$

$f(g(x)) :  1 + x + \frac{x^2}2$

Comment: Isn't the MacLaurin series of $f$ and $g$: $f(x)=1+x+\frac{x^2}2+O(x^3)$ and $g(x)=x+O(x^3)$ to be more accurate?

Comment: Everything is fine, up to the very last line. It should be $$f(x)g(x)=(1+x+x^2/2)x = x+x^2 + O(x^3)$$

Comment: @OP When you multiply $f$ and $g$, why (how?) do you get the same second-order expansion as for $f$?

Comment: The product of the two functions in the OP seems to have an error.

Comment: @ClementC. I took $fg$ to mean $f(g(x))$ so was using $e^{sin(x)}$ as my function

Comment: @Crostul I may have mistyped that last line, I worked it out as $f(g(x))$ rather than $f(x)g(x)$

Comment: @user337009 Then you should have written $f(g(x))$, not $f(x)g(x)$. OK, then everything is correct.

Comment: @Crostul Yes my mistake will edit. Is it correct then to take $fg$ from the question as meaning $f(g(x))$ rather than $f(x)g(x)$ ?

Comment: I'd deem it unlikely: i see almost always $f\circ g $ for composition.

Comment: @ClementC. in that case would they be looking for the Taylor polynomial for $f(x)g(x)$ or the product of their individual Taylor polynomials?

Comment: The former... but, how does that relate to the latter, in your opinion?

Comment: @ClementC. Assuming I've done this correctly it is $0 + x + x^{2}$ which appears to have the same coefficients on the $x$ terms as the product of the two polynomials.

Comment: You are somehow missing a 1/2 in the quadratic term - have you double checked?

Comment: @ClementC. I'm not entirely sure how I have, assuming the second derivative of $e^{x}\sin(x)$ is $2e^{x}\cos(x)$ then substituting $x = 0$ into that would give $2$ which when divided by $2!$ would leave the coefficient as $1$

Comment: My apologies, I was wrong (eyeballed the result instead of actually thinking). Incidentally, a good way to check: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+series+e%5Ex+sin(x)&t=crmtb01 More generally, the Taylor expansion of the product will be the product of the Taylor expansions (with the "right" order)

Comment: @ClementC. Many thanks for your help!

Comment: The tag [tag:euler-maclaurin] is not meant for questions about Maclaurin series. Please only use the tag [tag:taylor-expansion] in the future.